# Как получить html код открытой страницы python?

Tags: python

Есть простенький сайт на котором нужно правильно отвечать на всплывающие примеры, как можно получить html код открытого сайта, или же есть другая альтернатива (сама суть в том чтобы открыть сайт и потом запустить свой файл)
https://calcs.su/html/math/division-game.html
[image: Сам сайт]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос адрес сайта и уточните, что вы собираетесь делать с полученным html?

Comment: Чтобы зайдя на этот сайт со своего браузера, не открывая его через селениум, и запустив свой питон скрипт, начать решать примеры

Comment: по вашему описанию без селениум драйвера не обойтись... можете запустить его в "безголовом режиме", чтоб не мелькал... или эмулируйте запросы к сайту через requests и разбирайте html с bs4... какой сайт, все-таки?

Answer (score 1):

вот по такому примеру через bs4 cделайте свой)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req
    
resp = req.get("http://www.something.com")
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
 
print(soup.title)
print(soup.title.text)
print(soup.title.parent)
```